# How to fix proxy errors?

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications

I'm trying to figure out how to create jsp files in netbeans. So I know I have to first create a new project making it a web application but I don't have the option to do so. So I tried to download the plugin but I keep getting this error:

**Networking problem in http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/files/nbms/z8930_dukewizard-2.1.nbm
Check your proxy settings or try again later. The server may be unavailable at the moment. You may also want to make sure that your firewall is not blocking network traffic. Your cache may be out of date. Please click Check for Updates to refresh content.**

I have no idea what that means or how to fix it.

Comment: The plugin can't connect to the internet. The error suspects you are behind a corporate firewall and need to configure the plugin or netbeans to use a proxy to get to the internet outside the proxy. But, it also suggests checking your internet connection outside a corporate env or clearing the cache.

Comment: how do i confugure the plugin?

Comment: Actually, it looks like the entire plugin site is down.  [netbeans plugin site](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/) gives a similar error in Chrome. Can't remember the last time I used netbeans so not sure how long its been down.

Comment: So is there no way to fix it then? Do I just have to wait until the site comes back up??